# Pandas: Starting from the second row. subtract from previous row and use it as value to the next subtraction

Tags: python, pandas

### Context

I need to code an algorithm using Pandas to, starting from the second row, subtract a column value from the previous row, and use the result to keep subtracting the next row, etc.

### Example

```
INPUT:
ID    VALUE
0       1
1       10
2       30
3       45
4       78

OUTPUT (just the result, not the operation itself):
ID    VALUE
0       1
1       9  #(10-1)
2       21 #(30-9)
3       24 #(45-21)
4       54 #(78-24)
```

### What I Tried

```
df['VALUE'] = df['VALUE'] - df['VALUE]'.shift() # Doesn't starts with the second row, and use the original dataframe to subtract

df['VALUE'] = df['VALUE'].diff() # Doesn't starts with the second row, and use the original dataframe to subtract
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Numpy, `cumsum` with alternating sign

```
i = np.arange(len(df))
j = np.arange(2)

a = np.where(
    (i[:, None] + j) % 2 == 0, 1, -1
) * df.VALUE.values[:, None]

b = a.cumsum(0)[i, i % 2]

df.assign(VALUE=b)

   ID  VALUE
0   0      1
1   1      9
2   2     21
3   3     24
4   4     54
```

---

#### Explanation

First thing is to notice that

```
X0 ->                     X0
X1 ->                X1 - X0
X2 ->           X2 - X1 + X0
X3 ->      X3 - X2 + X1 - X0
X4 -> X4 - X3 + X2 - X1 + X0
```

So I wanted to multiply every other row by negative one... but I needed to do this twice for the other choice of alternating rows.

I needed to generate a mask that swaps between + and - 1 for both options

```
i = np.arange(len(df))
j = np.arange(2)

m = np.where(
    (i[:, None] + j) % 2 == 0, 1, -1
)

m

array([[ 1, -1],
       [-1,  1],
       [ 1, -1],
       [-1,  1],
       [ 1, -1]])
```

Now I need to broadcast multiply this across my `df.VALUE`

```
a = m * df.VALUE.values[:, None]

a

array([[  1,  -1],
       [-10,  10],
       [ 30, -30],
       [-45,  45],
       [ 78, -78]])
```

Notice the pattern.  Now I `cumsum`

```
a.cumsum(0)

array([[  1,  -1],
       [ -9,   9],
       [ 21, -21],
       [-24,  24],
       [ 54, -54]])
```

But I need the positive ones... more specifically, I need the alternating ones.  So I slice with a modded `arange`

```
b = a.cumsum(0)[i, i % 2]
b

array([ 1,  9, 21, 24, 54])
```

This is what I ended up assigning to the existing column

```
df.assign(VALUE=b)

   ID  VALUE
0   0      1
1   1      9
2   2     21
3   3     24
4   4     54
```

This produces a copy of `df` and overwrites the `VALUE` column with `b`.
To persist this answer, make sure to reassign to a new name or `df` if you want.

```
df_new = df.assign(VALUE=b)
```

Comment: Wow, didn't even knew that cumsum existed. Great work, thank you very much. I just don't understand the df.assign part...

Comment: Nice explanation of the problem and breakdown with pattern recognition.  +1

Comment: Thanks @ScottBoston (-:

Answer (score 3):

It is hard to say whether there is a pandas' way to do it so , I asked this question couple month ago. And below are my solution.

```
l=[]
for x,y in enumerate(df.VALUE):
    if x ==0: 
       l.append(y)
    else : 
       l.append(y-l[x-1])
l
Out[20]: [1, 9, 21, 24, 54]
```

Comment: I don't actually need to use a pandas method/function. Your solution worked out perfectly, but now I have to set this list as each one of the column VALUE, or even a new column DIFFVALUE.

Comment: df['DIFF']=l @Lodi

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"ID": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], 
                   "VALUE": [1, 10, 30, 45, 78]})
cumsum_with_parity = df.groupby(df.index % 2).VALUE.cumsum()
df["VALUE"] = cumsum_with_parity - cumsum_with_parity.shift().fillna(0)
```

Comment: Nice, solution with `groupby` and `cumsum` @Colin.  +1